# Ubuntu got uninstalled automatically

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 along with Windows 10 in my Lenovo ideapad and it was working great until today.

During the normal reboot procedure to get into the Ubuntu OS, 'system tools', the last option in the list, was selected by mistake; apparently there is some problem with the down-arrow key of my keypad. When the BIOS screen appeared, no tab was available to quit from the appeared screen. So, as it was written 'Click enter to go to set up', by mistake, I clicked ENTER and alas my screen was booted to Windows and I can't go back to my Ubuntu partition any more.

Any help to get back to Ubuntu will be appreciated. I spent some three days to complete the installations of necessary languages in it. I wanna retrieve them back without any loss of information.

The Boot-info can be viewed [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzc5ybDSxLz-NkVRMmRmbnB4dmc/view?usp=sharing).

Thank you.

Comment: Problem solve aayo?

Comment: Nope! Some problem endu

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: I have given the link to Boot-Info! And I sorted the issue out. Thanks.

Comment: Okey adutha prashnam undakkiyittu veendum varika :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make a live flash drive, and install boot repair on it and follow the instructions.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

boot-repair
```

You can get more details at: https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

From Windows, I went to my Ubuntu OS using the steps to go into the BIOS in Windows 10. After running these four commands, the Boot Repair window appeared and 'recommended repair' was selected as given in the link you provided. But, instead of the window supposed to open as shown in the link, one mentioning 'An error occurred during the repair' appeared.

Comment: it  says 'The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 17.04] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
'

Comment: Try using a tool like GParted to create the partition.

Comment: And one more thing: When I reboot and go into BIOS, using Ubuntu mounted USB flash drive, I can go back to my Ubuntu account and use it as before; there is no 'Try Ubuntu' option that appears'. Only problem is every time, I have to boot into Windows and then use reboot options available in Windows to boot into Ubuntu; no GRUB window appears. Sorry I didn't mention this before.

I will see how to create a boot-partition using GParted. My question, how did something which was working properly suddenly disappeared.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I sorted the issue out! During reboot, instead of USB UEFI, I was selecting USB all along. That's why I said no "Try Ubuntu without installing " was visible. Now, it's alright. The trial version was accessed and the above four commands were run and it was successful. Thanks a lot. :)